# Audience claim on identityserver4 code flow access token is wrong

Tags: c#, asp.net, identityserver4, openid-connect

I'm using code flow for a vuejs client with Identityserver4.
i added `RequirePkce` and i can get the access token and id token from oidc-client.
but access token `aud` claim is pointing back to Identityserver4 base address not my api resource.
can something be wrong ?

Client:

```
new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "js.admin",
                    ClientName = "admin dashboard vuejs client.",

                    RequirePkce = true,
                    RequireClientSecret = false,
                    RequireConsent = false,
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,

                    RedirectUris = new List<string>
                    {
                        "http://localhost:8080",
                        "http://localhost:8080/logincb.html",
                        "http://localhost:8080/silent-renew.html"
                    },
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string>
                    {
                        "http://localhost:8080/",
                        "http://localhost:8080"
                    },
                    AllowedCorsOrigins = new List<string>
                    {
                        "http://localhost:8080"
                    },
                    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                    {
                        "openid",
                        "role",
                        "profile",
                        "api1.rw",
                        "email",
                        "phone"
                    }
                }
```

oidc client setting:

```
const clientSettings = {
      userStore: new WebStorageStateStore({ store: window.localStorage }),
      authority: STS_DOMAIN,
      client_id: "js.admin",
      redirect_uri: "http://localhost:8080/logincb.html",
      automaticSilentRenew: true,
      silent_redirect_uri: "http://localhost:8080/silent-renew.html",
      response_type: "code",
      scope: "openid profile api1.rw role email phone",
      post_logout_redirect_uri: "http://localhost:8080/",
      filterProtocolClaims: true
    };
```

Access token decoded:

```
 "iss": "http://localhost:5001",
 "aud": "http://localhost:5001/resources",
```

as you can see the both issuer and audience claims are the same with is wrong.

but even scopes are correct.
I really appreciate any help.

```
Bearer was not authenticated. Failure message: IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences: 'http://localhost:5001/resources'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidAudience: 'api1' or validationParameters.ValidAudiences: 'null'.
```

its is the last error i got.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The http://localhost:5001/resources is a generic resource that is added when you have not defined or associated any ApiResources with the requested ApiScope.

From the documentation [here](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/fundamentals/resources/api_scopes/), it says:

> When using the scope-only model, no aud (audience) claim will be added
> to the token since this concept does not apply. If you need an aud
> claim, you can enable the EmitStaticAudienceClaim setting on the
> options. This will emit an aud claim in the issuer_name/resources
> format. If you need more control of the aud claim, use API resources.

To get **api1.rw** as your audience, you need to add a **ApiResource** to your IdentityServer configuration. You can name the **ApiResource** and **ApiScope** **api1.rw**

To complement this answer, I write a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic:
[IdentityServer – IdentityResource vs. ApiResource vs. ApiScope](https://nestenius.se/2023/02/02/identityserver-identityresource-vs-apiresource-vs-apiscope/)

Comment: i didn't put the code but i defined api resource too. and api1.rw is my apiscope that attached to api resources api1

Comment: can you post your ApiScope and ApiResource definition to your question?

Comment: you can also set this flag EmitStaticAudienceClaim (in IdentityServer) to false to remove the generic resources audience.

Comment: i know i might look a little dumb but error was due to the wrong way of adding in memory api resources to services. :) really thank for the time. you save my day <3.